# How to limit Interval time between 2 click in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do I limit Interval time between 2 clicks in jQuery?

```
$('button').click(function(){
  // do some stuff
}
```

After the first click, how do I wait one second, then the next click will effect. thanks.

Comment: Do you want to achieve two different effects with each click?

Comment: @WillemLabu, no, one button for same effects, in fact, this click send ajax request to another page.

Comment: What I mean is, what should the first click do, and what should the second click do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a way to *throttle* the clicks. Have a look at the [jQuery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) by Ben Alman.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var clicked = false;
$('button').click(function(){
  // do some stuff
  if (!clicked){
      alert('true');
      clicked = true;
      setTimeout(function(){ clicked = false; }, 1000); 
  } else {
      return false;    
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Preventing double Ajax requests

```
$("button").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    // save button context
    var ctx = this;

    if (ctx.preventAjax === false)
    {
        ctx.preventAjax = true;

        // make a request
        $.ajax({
            ...
            complete: function() {
                delete ctx.preventAjax;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Not using attributes on elements is faster than using those and checking them on each click.

Answer (score 0):

After first click you can disable the button untill your ajax finshed.

```
$('button').click(function(){         
     $('button').attr('disabled',true); //disable the button
     // do some stuff
       $('button').attr('disabled',false);//enable button back .(most probably u need to write it in success event of ajax request)
 }
```